# Get value of inherited background

Tags: wpf, popup

I have a user control in which I have a popup that occasionally hides the rest of the control. Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="myGrid">
    <!-- Some stuff -->
    </Grid>
    <Popup Width="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=ActualWidth}"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=myGrid}"
           Placement="Relative">
        <Border Name="popupBorder">
            <Grid>
            <!--- Slightly different stuff --->
            <Grid>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

...and that works nicely except of course I need to set a background. I would like the popup-hides-everything transition to be as seamless as possible so it'd be nice if my popup and the rest of my control shared the same background.

I have been unable to figure out how to do this when the usercontrol doesn't have a background explicitly set.

I have tried this (in XAML):

```
<Border Name="popupBorder" Background="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=Background}" />
```

I have tried this (in code):

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var brush = this.GetValue(UserControl.BackgroundProperty);
        popupBorder.Background = (Brush)brush;
    }
```

In all cases the border's background is 'null' and the popup is just a big black block. Is there a way to do this?

(In case you want to tell me that there's just a better way to do what I'm trying to do ... I have a long list; I want to display the first few items with a "See more" button; the whole mess is in an ItemsControl and I don't want the "See more" button to resize the items - hence, show the long list on a popup.)

Comment: but `myGrid` doesn't have `Background` defined so it will be null as well

Comment: You don't say. And yet, unlike my popup, at run time it *does* have a background. Do you know how I can find the value of that background and assign it to my popup? 'Cause that's what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: `Grid` has background or something else has background? `Grid` by default won't have background unless you set it and I don't see that in your code. Maybe something else sets `Background` through `Style`. Also if you want `Popup` to support transparency then you need to set [`AllowsTransparency="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.allowstransparency(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise everything that is transparent will be black

Comment: Did you can check with [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), for example, what gives that background?

Comment: Yes. I did check with Snoop. It says the source is "Default". Well, actually, the background for the user control is from "Default" and everything else is from the "ParentTemplate". That's just fantastic - can I assign that "Default" to my popup as well?

Comment: And don't tell me `Grid` doesn't have a background by default. Of course if does - Open a new project, drop a grid in the main window and run it. Does is show up as a black rectangle? No? Then it has some sort of background assigned by default.

Comment: No, `Grid` doesn't have background by default. `Window` has. Actually `Border` in a `Window` has (check with Snoop). Snoop shows _Default_ background value for `Grid` which in this case means null which visually appears as transparent. `Background` is not inherited like `DataContext` so `Grid` does not inherit background of a `Window` it just shows it through. In this empty project, that you mention, set `Window.Background` and you'll see background changes then set background of a `Grid` and you'll see it covers background of a `Window`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52019/discussion-between-mcwyrm-and-dkozl)

Answer (score 1):

After getting some advice from [dkozl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1432140/dkozl) I was able to implement the following solution:

```
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        puBorder.Background = findBackground(this) ?? SystemColors.ControlBrush;
    }

    private Brush findBackground(DependencyObject element)
    {
        var parent = element;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            var p = parent as Control;
            if (p != null && p.Background != null)
                return p.Background;
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried to do the same thing in a converter but the converter executes before the control is added to the visual tree (I assume, anyway - it didn't have a visual parent) and so it wasn't useful.